# How can I add a line including single quotes to a file with sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

I want to append the following line to a text file with sed:

```
gem 'forum2discourse'
```

I've tried `sed -i '$a gem \'forum2discourse\'' Gemfile` but this drops me to a `>` prompt so I think I must be incorrectly escaping the `'` characters

Comment: `sed -i "\$a gem \'forum2discourse\'" file`, or just `echo "gem 'forum2discourse'" >> file`...

Comment: or try `sed -i '$a gem '"'forum2discourse'" Gemfile`

Answer (score 4):

`sed -i '$a gem '"'"'forum2discourse'"'" Gemfile`

#### Alternate Solution

If you wish to do it your way, then use the bash `$'string'` format. Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

```
sed -i $'$a gem \'forum2discourse\'' Gemfile
```

Source: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Answer (score 1):

At least with GNU sed:

```
sed -i.bak '$a gem \x27forum2discourse\x27' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e '$a gem '"'"'forum2discourse'"'" yourfile
```

Comment: No single quotes, as specified in the question...

Comment: has been updated....